# map Crawled property to managed property using Client Object Model C# in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, enterprise-search

is there any way we can map crawled properties to managed properties using CSOM using C#?
i am not able to find any code samples for the same

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly manipulate Managed Properties with CSOM. What you can do is Export working Search Settings from a site and then Import that settings XML via CSOM.

There is an example of how to do this on the SharePoint PnP repo. https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.SearchSettingsPortability

You can use something like:

```
private static void ExportSearchSettings(ClientContext context, string settingsFile)
{
   SearchConfigurationPortability sconfig = new SearchConfigurationPortability(context);
   SearchObjectOwner owner = new SearchObjectOwner(context, SearchObjectLevel.SPWeb);
   ClientResult<string> configresults = sconfig.ExportSearchConfiguration(owner);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
   string results = configresults.Value;
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(settingsFile, results);
}

private static void ImportSearchSettings(ClientContext context, string settingsFile)
{
   SearchConfigurationPortability sconfig = new SearchConfigurationPortability(context);
   SearchObjectOwner owner = new SearchObjectOwner(context, SearchObjectLevel.SPWeb);
   sconfig.ImportSearchConfiguration(owner, System.IO.File.ReadAllText(settingsFile));
   context.ExecuteQuery();            
}
```

From: [PnP Search Customization Guidance](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/articles/search-customizations-for-sharepoint.md)